# Angular sharing data among other components not working properly

Tags: angular, typescript, behaviorsubject

I am trying to use BehaviorSubject to share data between my components

Below is the code to my service

```
import {Injectable, Optional, SkipSelf} from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UrlService {
  private previousUrl: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject(null);
  public previousUrl$: Observable<string> = this.previousUrl.asObservable();

  constructor(@Optional() @SkipSelf() parent?: UrlService) {
    if (parent) {
      throw Error(
        `[UrlService]: trying to create multiple instances,
        but this service should be a singleton.`
      );
    }
  }

  setPreviousUrl(previousUrl: string) {
    this.previousUrl.next(previousUrl);
  }

}
```

I have a first component in which I set the value as below. If I try to retrieve the value set in ngInit it works with the component.

```
constructor(private urlService:UrlService){
}

ngOnInit(): void {
this.urlService.setPreviousUrl(this.router.url.toString());
}
```

I have a second component in which I try to retrieve the value as below, I get null. I suspects that a different instances are created.

```
constructor(private urlService:UrlService){
}

ngOnInit(): void {
this.urlService.previousUrl$
  .subscribe((previousUrl) => {
    this.referer = previousUrl // it is always null
  });
}
```

Comment: is that second component declared in eagerly loaded or lazily loaded module?

Comment: Nope its only 1 instance as it is placed into the root injector

Comment: Did you set changeDetectionStrategy to OnPush in your consuming component?

Comment: Nesan maybe you are setting it to null.

Comment: I have issues with the code: 1) its not a complete example - only claims and statements that "this works and this does not". 2) you are not verifying what value is actually passed to `next` method. 3) You have provided no indication what is your fitness function is - meaning how do you know it is working or not 4) you are not verifying that you are actually emiting any values - thus initial NULL value. What you have provided is fine and would work as intended meaning that something else is wrong either with surrounding code or your persception of how things work.

Comment: I know it is working within the same component. That is because I have tested it.

Comment: @pascalpuetz I don't think that change strategy would change anything. Moreover, I am not using  Input ().

Comment: @Antoniossss Of course, you clearly see the value I am passing to the next function. It is a String. You also see that in the ngInit of my first component, I am setting it. I am not showing the rest because it is pure business logic. I have shown enough of what is required to replicate problem. I would encourage you to do the example. The is a link to an example(very minimal) :  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-getting-previous-url-euc7hs?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: @NesanMano FYI change detection strategy is not about `@Inputs` but about reflecting changes of the component state in UI - which may or may not origin from changes in the `@Input` fields

Comment: Works fine in the link you have provided.

Comment: The same thing does simply not work between components in my app.

Comment: @NesanMano it would, since the change might be there but not reflected in the ui. OnPush would mean that you would need to run the changedetection yourself, since you are not using the async pipe but subscribe to the observable manually.